# How to create an Intent in React-Native and pass Data to it?

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, android-intent

I was wondering how does one start up a React-Native application and have the data in the intent when the application is launched, so that I can reference it in one of my React-Native components?

I put this intent-filter under my MainActivity in the mainfest:

```
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
  <data android:mimeType="text/*" />
</intent-filter>
```

and then in MainActivity.java:

```
@Override
    protected ReactActivityDelegate createReactActivityDelegate() {
        return new ReactActivityDelegate(this, getMainComponentName()) {
            @Override
            protected Bundle getLaunchOptions() {
                Intent intent = MainActivity.this.getIntent();
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putString("test", "Test Data");
                return bundle;
            }
        };
    }
```

and then I tried referencing the "test" field in my app.js of my React Native:

```
componentDidMount() {
  console.log(this.props.test);
}
```

However, the this.props.test is undefined, but it's supposed to say "Test Data" since I put that in the bundle of the MainActivity.java.